# Font awesome icons will change color if inline the style but not if it's in external stylesheet

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I've been Googling around and can't seem to find any info on this.

In short, if I inline the colors for my Font Awesome icons, the colors change. If I put the same style selectors in my external stylesheet, no color change.

Here's the html:

```
<i class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-official facebook-color"></i>
<i class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square twitter-color"></i>
<i class="fa fa-3x fa-linkedin-square linkedin-color"></i>
<i class="fa fa-3x fa-pinterest-square pinterest-color"></i>
<i class="fa fa-3x fa-envelope-square email-color"></i>
```

If I inline the color styles they change:

```
<style type="text/css">
.facebook-color {color:#3b5998}
.twitter-color {color:#55acee}
.linkedin-color {color:#0077b5}
.pinterest-color {color:#bd081c}
.email-color {color:black} 
</style>
```

But if I put the exact same styles in my external stylesheet, there is no color change.

One note:

I grab Font Awesome with the CDN, maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com

My sites at www.example.com and my static files like css and js are served from static.example.com. Is there some sort of cross domain issue that would cause the stylesheet not to work but explain why the inline works?

Comment: there might be style overwrite by some different style definition

Comment: But those selectors e.g..pinterest-color are only in the style sheet once. There's no other definition for those classes.

Comment: may be it would be inherited.. check in the element inspector...